# How to cluster two microservices running on different servers using vert.x?

Tags: microservices, vert.x

suppose I have two microservices ( Service A and service B), now I deploy service A on an aws server and service B on a Digital Ocean server. How can I use vert.x clustering to achieve communication between the two processes using the vert.x event bus. I have been able achieve this when both services are running on the same machine.One of the solutions I could come up with was this:-

Run a hazlecast clustering service separately on a separate machine and configure service A and service B so that they connect to the common clustering service( when I say service, it could just be the hazlecast service running through the command line), if there are better ways to achieve this, please do suggest them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast has different plugins for discovery within a single cloud. But for multicloud I believe your only resort is to hardcode the node IP addresses:

```
<network>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>aws-host</member>
            <member>digitalocean-host</member>
        </tcp-ip>
    </join>
</network>
```